# Oops, those icons are unexpected

Tags: bug, status-completed

After I went to https://stackexchange.com/leagues/283/alltime/softwarerecs the icons are unexpected:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using FF 56.0

Comment: This is not Software Recommendations specific. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302027/theres-something-not-quite-right-with-the-achievements-drop-down-on-stackexchan

Comment: Apart from which: for me (FF55) they look OK.